Easily see applied usings with implicit usings activated
Implicit usings is nice as it removes a lot of boilerplate, but sometimes I catch myself wanting to easily see which dependencies a specific file has. Not even after decompiling the dll the implicit usings are shown.
Is there any neat way to check this?
Now, I do one of these, not neat ways:

Hovering over each class
Turning off implicit usings and import all missing usings, and then revert


For decompiling I usually use dotPeek, which doesn't show the usings (might be some setting I'm not aware of).
I googled for alternatives and tried out ILSpy VS extension which actually does the job!
I don't mark this as correct answer yet, if anyone knows a way that doesn't require external tools, that would be preferable.


Visual Studio shows a "global 'using' directive" icon in the top-left corner of the editor:

If you click it, it will reveal your global usings. This includes the ones from the project template (*.GlobalUsings.g.cs) as well as your explicitly declared global usings.
This does, however, not show the dependencies, as always all the global usings will be listed. But still a nice feature.
It helps to set the following Visual Studio Option:

You can then simply click on a directive in the pop-up shown in the first image to open the corresponding global usings file and to see the faded out directives.
Btw., I wonder why they have chosen to include System.Net.Http in a WinForms project (shown in the image above).

Thanks, didn't know about that. Didn't answer the question though, and as I tend to keep global usings in a separate file, this doesn't add much value. Good question about System.Net.Http, according to this link it's removed, a bit vague what they're referring to though, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview#implicit-using-directives.

Comment after edit:
I'd like to see the usings for a specific file, not which usings global usings that are unused for the whole project, see the gif below in my answer, where I can check the usings that applies for a specific file.
